# Unable to capture the form select value , php

Tags: php, html, validation, html-select

After reading a number of posts on here, on how to capture the Select values in my html form, I understand the principle but I cant seem to execute it flawlessly in my code below.
$selected_val isn't being appended. perhaps its empty? What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

**Desired result:**
test@test.com is an **A-user** ,

**Current result:**
test@test.com is an  ,

Here is how my HTML form looks:

```
<form method="POST" class="subscription-form form-inline  id="subscribe" role="form">

<h4 class="subscription-success"><i class="icon_check"></i> Thank you for requesting... </h4>
<h4 class="subscription-error">Something Wrong!</h4>

<select name="usertype" class="form-control input-box">
    <option selected value="A-user">I'm an A user</option>
    <option value="B-user">I'm an B user</option>
    <option value="C-user">I'm an C user</option>
</select>
<input type="email" name="email" id="subscriber-email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control input-box">

<button type="submit" name="submit" id="subscribe-button" class="btn btn-default standard-button">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Here is my php:

```
<?php 
   if ( isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

    $selected_val = $_POST['usertype'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable

    $e_mail = $_POST['email'] . " is a " . $selected_val . " ," . "\n";
file_put_contents('email-list.txt', $e_mail, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
} 
?>
```

Comment: where is the form tag

Comment: Your `<form>` is missing a `method="POST"`. Without it, the default is `method="GET"`.

Comment: @IndraKumarS the form opening tag was hiding due to formatting.

Comment: Please read [Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) from the manual first before asking questions.

Comment: Also, use `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` instead of `filter_var()`.

Comment: @Ja͢ck haha, I have read that, amongst a large number of other online sources, from my many minutes of googling. You have read it just like myself. Is there anything you can see that I need to do to achieve my desired result?

Comment: The first thing I would do is add debugging statements, e.g. `print_r($_POST);`. Second, make sure you actually have write permissions to that file.

Answer (score 1):

Your form is missing method attribute

Post method should be there

```
<form action="your.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

`<form>` element should have `method` attribute like

```
<form method="POST" class="subscription-form form-inline wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" id="subscribe" role="form">
```

And **NOTE** in your PHP code, the user will click the submit button so check

```
  if ( isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    selected_val = $_POST['usertype'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    $e_mail = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $e_mail = $e_mail . " - is a - " .$selected_val . " ," . "\n";
   file_put_contents('email-list.txt', $e_mail, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
```

Comment: Thank for the Tip on the 'method' attribute. I added it and updated my post here. But this hasn't solved my problem which I expected. In regards to your PHP suggestion, I get what you are saying but i still want to check if the input field isset and validate it as well.  You just seem to remove/replace the code I need as well.

Comment: The values will be getting submitted only when the user clicks the submit button, so you can check if $_POST['submit'] is set and inside that you can check if $_POST['email'] is set or not

Comment: First of all, what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, per se. in my code I'm appending the form data on a text file. but its blank where the $selected_val should be

Comment: Before appending it to a text file first use print_r($_POST); to check whether you are getting all the form values

Comment: Since in your if condition you have checked for email, if it is not set the above code will never work

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me at all. it no longer saves to the file when I used this answers code. At least my original code saves the email to the file, just not the option value - which all I'm missing and desire to achieve.

Comment: Any error occured? Did the execution atleast entered the if condition?